# Determine tweet location with Twitter API

Tags: twitter

How can I find the location of a specific user's tweet? What are the API methods and techniques that I need to go through to determine the location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**: The below assumes that you want to grab multiple tweets and find their locations. If you don't, and you just want a single tweet by it's id, use [`statuses/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid).

It's entirely possible - *if the user has enabled location for their tweet*. It'll be the value of the `coordinates` key, which will be null if they haven't.

Let's say you're using the following API method: `statuses/user_timeline`.

- This is a `GET` request
- The resource url is: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json`

You can specify either the `user_id` or `screen_name` as part of the `GET` parameters, for example: `?screen_name=J7mbo`.

In the tweet results, once `json_decode()` is run on them, one of the keys will look like this:

[image]

This is actually the first key, according to the documentation, so you should be able to find it and it's value pretty easily.

**Warning**

Do *not* get confused with the `location` sub-key underneath the `User` key. This is the location of the *user*, as per their profile, *not* the location of any specific tweet. Use the `coordinates` key for that.

[Documentation Link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)